# Adding different layout options from the 2D editor

Tags: godot

I would like to make the following views for portrait and landscape mode:

In portrait, show the views vertically as

A 
B 
C

(looks like they are in a VBox)

In landscape, show the views as

A C 
B

(looks like HBox(VBox(A, B), C))

I am able to do this with the use of a custom container, but it means measuring sizes myself, and requiring that all 3 nodes by immediate children in my container.

I was wondering if there was a different approach where we can define two completely separate layouts in the editor, and associate certain nodes with the nodes we want; this is a pattern I'm more familiar with through android dev, where we can create two completely different layouts and associate certain views by having the same id.

For this case, I would be able to create the layouts I mentioned above with the existing VBox and HBox, and tell the root note to place A, B, C where they should be. The children no longer need to be immediate children of the root container, and I can add other nodes to one of the layouts and not the other. If a user switches between these two layouts, I expect that the contents within the shared nodes (A, B, C) be retained.

Is there a way of doing something like this in Godot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you're describing by creating two separate layouts in the editor and instantiating + replacing when needed.

```
extends Control
        
const LANDSCAPE_LAYOUT = preload("res://Landscape.tscn")
const PORTRAIT_LAYOUT = preload("res://Portrait.tscn")
var orientation = 0
onready var layout = $Layout // root node of UI you will replace

func _process(delta):
    if orientation != OS.screen_orientation:
        _change_layout()


func _change_layout():
    orientation = OS.screen_orientation
    var new_layout = null
    match orientation:
        0:
            new_layout = LANDSCAPE_LAYOUT.instance()
        1:
            new_layout = PORTRAIT_LAYOUT.instance()
        _:
            return  // feel free to include the other cases in ScreenOrientation enum.

    var layout_position = layout.get_position_in_parent()
    remove_child(layout)
    add_child(new_layout)
    move_child(new_layout, layout_position)
    layout = new_layout
```

Similar to the Android activity lifecycle, you are destroying and recreating a portion of your UI whenever the orientation changes.

I'm checking orientation manually because there's no way to get a callback for it currently. If you're going to have multiple nodes checking the orientation, it might be useful to set up a singleton instead and emit a signal when it detects a change.

Comment: Will try this out. It seems like move_child is the key